# Disable Chrome Auto Reload on Timeout

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using debug extension for php (xdebug) to inspect some requests. That usually takes a long time. Until I've done debugging chrome doesn't get an html output and think that it should request page again. Which create an extra request that interrupting my debugging process and is quite annoying.

Previously it was possible to disable this by changing settings of `Enable Offline Auto-Reload Mode` and `Only Auto-Reload Visible Tabs` in `chrome://flags/`

like described in the accepted answer here: [Disable Chrome Auto Reload on Time Out Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575695/disable-chrome-auto-reload-on-time-out-error)

Unfortunately those flags are not available anymore.
Does anybody know a solution to this?