# Disable Chrome Auto Refresh on Time Out Error

Tags: google-chrome

for debugging my application I need some test on chrome Time Out Error page. but it frequently auto-refresh in the new version of chrome.
I want to disable auto-refresh on Time Out Error pages on chrome.

Previously it was possible to disable this by changing settings of Enable Offline Auto-Reload Mode and Only Auto-Reload Visible Tabs in chrome://flags/

like described in the accepted answer here: [Disable Chrome Auto Reload on Time Out Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575695/disable-chrome-auto-reload-on-time-out-error)

Unfortunately, those flags are not available anymore.
Does anybody know a solution to this?